# Animation Frame Rate Drop with Adblock Plus

Tags: performance, animation, adblock

I developed http://guyhollaway.co.uk/.

When Adblock Plus is disabled, the animation (and everything in general, really) for switching between pages is quite smooth and fluent. However, when enabled, he animation frame rate drops hugely and makes the site a bit sluggish.

I thought Adblock just blocks certain resources from loading after matching it against a database, however, nothing is being loaded when the animation is in progress.

What is the reason for the frame rate drop? And is there something I can do about it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Its very common for users to report poor browser performance with Adblock Plus installed. ABP needs 14,000+ filter list rules to work and requires significant CPU and memory overhead.

Your best bet is to use a lightweight adblocker and not a memory hog like Adblock Plus.

See this: https://github.com/gorhill/uBlock/wiki/uBlock-vs.-ABP:-efficiency-compared

And this: https://github.com/gorhill/uBlock/wiki/Who-cares-about-efficiency,-I-have-8-GB-and%7Cor-a-quad-core-CPU

Comment: I am aware of that. However, I can't see how ABP would need to test those 14,000 rules constantly. I can understand why it'd reduce page load performance, and other requests, but how can it be affecting the performance of animations?